# String or Binary data would be truncated: replacing the infamous error 8152

Tags: sql-server

I just tried to debug this problem on a server 2019 (15.0.2080.9) db compatibility 150
used following query to enable the warnings

```
use [db_name]

ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION
set VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS = on
go
```

forced the error but with `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE message_id = 2628` still get

> String or binary data would be truncated in table '%.*ls', column '%.*ls'. Truncated value: '%.*ls'.

Did I forget something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code that causes the error. That `SELECT` query will not force it.

Comment: It always raises the warning message but that message_id will be the old 8152 when `off` (with no table and column names) and the new 2628 when `on` (including them).

Comment: when you select from `sys.messages` you see the message *template*. Do something that would result in the truncation of string or binary data, and you'll see the template populated with the relevant values.